# New conjugate ?!

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

I've been playing with amazing Geogebra software and finally found a construction that perfectly fits the description of a *conjugate*. Apparently there is a plethora of remarkable properties associated with this one. It can be defined as the **circumcircular conjugate** with respect to the circumcenter of the triangle *ABC*. I am still hoping that it even might be a new one :)

However as I am only aware of the *cyclocevian*, *isotomic*, *isogonal* and *isocircular* conjugations and [there are lots of others listed in the ETC](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/glossary.html) it usually would be expected that this conjugate is not new and just a lesser known one.

This conjugation works as follows:

*R* is the circumcenter of the triangle *ABC*. *D* - is a random point. Draw a circumcircle for a triangle  *DRA*. *A1* is the intersection point of the circumcircle of *ABC* and this circle. Points *B1* and *C1* can be constructed in the exact same manner. Then, lines *AA1, BB1, CC1, RD* always intersect at some point *D1*. It can be shown that this operation can be applied in the reverse order. Choosing *D1* as the starting point we can construct points *B2*, *A2, C2* (Green circle is the circumcircle of the triangle *RBD1*) and lines *D1R*,  *BB2*, *AA2, CC2* intersect exactly at the initial point *D*. **So that apparently it is indeed a conjugate** [2](https://www.geogebra.org/m/c8xfvkyc). (This needs to be strictly proven though).

[image]

I decided to find the circumcircular conjugate of [the incenter of the triangle ABC](https://www.geogebra.org/m/q9xtgzse)

[image]

With the help of this construction we can get  points *I1,  J* that can be well known triangle centres... (or perhaps completely new ones)  **And finally we get the remarkable point X that is always lying on the circumcircle of the triangle ABC!  This *point X* is especially intriguing to me.  Could you please help me to identify it?**

Comment: it appears that 3 lines A1Oa, B1Ob, C1Oc intersect at some point X only for the incenter of the triangle ABC. In other words it is the special property of the incenter of ABC.

Comment: Nice discovery, congrats. Unfortunately this is not a new construction. Consider inversion with respect to the circumcircle of $ABC$ and you will see that $D_1$ is the image of $D$ under this inversion.

Comment: aah, ok!  The point X still remains a mystery, though.

Comment: if anyone is interested, point X has been kindly identified by the researchers who run the ETC as X(953).